# Multi-dimensional to Tabular mapping one column to several

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular, columnmappings

I have the following mapping within an old multi-dimensional cube:

[image]

Each one of these 3 INVOICE_FACT columns maps to the same sman_key column within the salesman table. I know within tabular that only one column is permitted to be mapped to another column.

How can I replicate this relationship within tabular?

Answer (score 0):

The two standard approaches to this issue are to either create multiple relationships between the two tables (only one relationship can be active at a time) or to import the `salesman` table multiple times with different names (e.g. `salesman`, `supervisor`, `driver`).

Without knowing more about the way that your data model is being used, it is hard to recommend the approach to use, but I tend to favour importing the `salesman` table multiple times.

If you use inactive relationships, a key function to know is the `USERELATIONSHIP()` function which specifies that a particular calculation is to occur using an inactive relationship.

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/userelationship-in-calculated-columns/ provides some example of this technique where the relationships are to a date dimension, and you want to have measures which accumulate sales amounts according to Order Date, Due Date, or Ship Date (as per AdventureWorks) e.g.

```
SalesByDueDate := 
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( FactInternetSales[SalesAmount] ),
        USERELATIONSHIP (
           FactInternetSales[DueDateKey],
           DimDate[DateKey]
        )
    )
```